# Drupal cck checkbox with global setting

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-fapi, drupal-node-hook

I am creating a "sticky" checkbox for my content type "news". this means that one news node is sticky, and is used in a banner like box.

This is marked by a checkbox int the cck create content form.

The checkbox is handled by the node_api,

so I check: if $op = 'update' and $node->type = 'news' then ... logic.

I don't know why but this doesn't seem like the best way to do it, because all my noe handling is done there.

Is ther a more logic way/place to handle this ?

@edit,

I also have to create an extra module to activate this. I have a "general" module which handles a few of this general things"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a set_variable for the sticky which stores the Node_ID.

This way, when I make a content Item sticky all the rest is made "Unsticky".

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to unset the "sticky" checkbox when a new "news" node is created, then yes this is probably the most straightforward way. I haven't tried it, but you might be able to do that using the Rules and Actions modules as well.

If you don't need to unset the old "sticky" field when a new "news" node is set as sticky, then you could just use a View that returns the single most recent "news" node that has the sticky field set. Then you can display the View results.